# Select option issue

Tags: javascript

I created a small code that for some strange reason it works badly.

With the first var declare variables, but it is just to let you see for what they are, aren't declared there. Opt is an array containing all the values ​​read from a file, alunno is a select , and trovata it's a counter that tells me how many rows there are.

Everything so far works fine, but in the while loop, where am I going to perform the adding in the select if I have for example two values ​​to be loaded, the first option is replaced with the second so instead of finding myself:

John, Antoine in the select, I find:

> Antoine, Antoine.

Which is quite strange considering that John is added initially, but then is replaced by the last value. 
What's wrong with this code?

```
var opt, elaborazione;  
var alunno = document.getElementById('alunno');  
var trovata = 0;

while(true)
{
    opt = new Option();
    elaborazione = v[count].split(";");
    elaborazione = elaborazione.slice(0,2);
    elaborazione = elaborazione.join(" "); 
    opt.text = elaborazione;
    alunno.add(opt);
    trovata--;
    if(trovata == 0){break;}    
}
```

more details:

```
while(!flow.AtEndOfStream) 
        {
            var lettura = flow.ReadLine();
            opts = lettura.split(';');
            count++;
            v[count] = lettura;
        }
```

Comment: What is `v`?  Can you give an example of what is in it?

Comment: i have added v with the firs while loop

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is in `v`, or what is in `flow`?

Comment: you are solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing `count` in the loop:

```
while(true)
{
    opt = new Option();
    elaborazione = v[count].split(";"); //The count is the same here
    //...
    trovata--;
    if(trovata == 0){break;}    
}
```

Thus you always use the last item of `v`, which is always the same.

Comment: count function good but the problem is in the meachanis that add the option